# Как сохранить неактивность нескольких кнопок?

Tags: java

Предположим у нас есть 2 класса меню и настройки, в меню есть 3 кнопки:

1 - скрывает меню и открывает настройки, но после нажатия на неё она становится неактивной;

2 - делает все тоже что и кнопка 1;

3 - выход;

Внимание проблема: после возвращения обратно из класса настройки в класс меню и после нажатия в меню кнопки 1 или 2, то первая кнопка для которой была задана команда - быть неактивной, становится активной;

Внимание вопрос: как сохранить их состояние неактивности или невидимости, если брать команду setvisible?

P.s такая простая ситуация вызывает множество проблем и ставит в тупик

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вам надо где-то хранить ваши настройки/ссостояние кнопок (в БД, например или просто в тектовом файле/`*.properties` файле) и при входе на экран загружать его, настраивая изначальное состояние кнопок согласно сохранённой информации.

Comment: А не могли бы вы пример использования properties написать? По сайтам полазил, видео посмотрел, но там много лишнего

Comment: С записью разобрался, теперь нужно как-то изменить содержимое

Comment: @Митяй, я с этим работал только через `groovy` и только на чтение. По идее должны быть либо встроенные либо сторонние решения для работы с ними. В крайнем случае можете просто полностью файл перезаписывать каждый раз

Comment: Можно пример "встроенного" решения пожалуйста

Comment: Похоже, что встроенных нет. Но есть либы. Вот, например: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15522238/3212712

Comment: Помогите пожалуйста в этой теме, тоже с property https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/272901/%D0%9C%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8F%D0%B9

Comment: @Митяй, по ссылке ваш профиль, вопроса там нет)

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/801581/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8-%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D0%B2%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%89%D0%B0%D1%8E%D1%89%D0%B8%D0%B9%D1%81%D1%8F-%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%D1%82

Comment: @Митяй, я с таким никогда не работал, засим не могу сказать ничего. Наверное вам придётся там как-то рассчитывать в пикселях размеры букв и сравнивать их с экраном. Либо стандартные виджеты для текста использовать - они по умолчанию текст переносят